# Does the size or type of EC2 instance effect the autoscaling/provisioning/termination time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Are any of the EC2 provisioning/termination times effected by the size or type of instance. For example, if I provision an m4.large and an m4.xlarge, will the m4.large be provisioned faster? Or if I provision an m4.large and an m5.large, will the m5.large be provisioned faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of stages that may be affected by the instance type:

- *Provisioning* as in **allocating the resources on AWS infrastructure** and creating the VM.

  I don't think there would be a noticeable difference for *on-demand* instances since Amazon reserves the capacity for on-demand. I haven't measured that though.

  If you're using *spot instances* then there may be a delay for some instance types that are in high-demand.
- *Provisioning* as in **starting the operating system**.

  Yes, larger instances get set up faster because they get more CPU capacity, more memory, generally they get faster disk and network throughput, etc.

  There is a very noticeable difference between starting up e.g. `t2.micro` and `m4.xlarge` with the latter being done much faster. Not sure if you can measure any difference between e.g. `m4.xlarge` and `m5.xlarge` - I wouldn't think it would be noticeable.

Interesting question though, I would love to see some real stats on this!

Hope that helps :)